# Core Data rare crash "Dispatch queue: SQLQueue 0x1..."

Tags: core-data

I have an odd crash in my app that's difficult to reproduce. I did run into some threading issues before which seem to be mostly fixed now but every now and then I receive a crash log, even on my own devices.

My code fetches `Library`s descending by the last time a book was added. For each of these libraries I want to see the most recently added books. The code works (except for the crash) but I can't think of a reason for the crash itself.

I apologize for the weird unwrapping at `if let libraries1 = libraries0 {` etc. but to me it seemed to have improved the situation which also may however only be imagination.

The last possible cause of issue that I may spot by myself is to declare `libraries` outside of the thread of the mainContext however I'm not sure if that can be the root of the problem since I would expect the crash to be way more present if it was a hard "don't".

Below you will see my code, the `// CRASH:` comment indicates the line that Xcode blames the crash on.

```
func readEntries( count: Int = 3, completion: @escaping ([Data], [String]) -> () ) {
    
    var libraries = [Library]()
    
    let fetchRequest = makeFetchRequest(LIBRARY)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastAddedTime", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = count
    
    mainContext.perform {
        
        do {
            let libraries0 = try self.mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Library]
            if let libraries1 = libraries0 {

                libraries = libraries1
                
                for lib in libraries {
                    
                    if(lib.lastAddedTime > 0) {

                        let fetchRequest = self.makeFetchRequest(self.BOOK)
                        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 5

                        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "hostLibrary == %@", lib)
                        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
                        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "time", ascending: false)]

                        if var books = try? self.mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Book] {  // CRASH: "Dispatch queue: SQLQueue 0x1020206e0 for DBBookModel.sqlite (0)"

                            print(books)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                //completion ...
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not load. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: No error message in console?

Comment: Hey @Larme I have never had this crash happen in a session with Xcode, I only see the crash logs from users and sometimes in my own devices

Comment: core data is not thread safe - neither for reading or for writing. If you access core date from the wrong thread, it can crash later the next time you access core data, even if you are accessing correctly then. This makes it very hard to track down these crashes. Look at other places in your app that you might not be using the right thread.

Comment: unrelated to the crash, you should be using relationship to get related objects, not making a second fetch. relationships are much, much faster.